# Latest version for mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the latest mysql version? is it v5.2 or v5.1?

Comment: What would you say?: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/

Comment: @Sharpeye500, I've voted to close this question as "too localised" as in a months time (for example), any answers may be no longer relevant, plus it's very easy to find the answer by visiting mysql.com! =)

Comment: Yeah, this really should be found out on the downloads page. Voting to close as too localized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5.1 is GA, 5.2 is in beta.